# How can I access variables from within an ansible module?

Tags: ansible

I'd like to be able to set configuration variables for my ansible modules as standard host/group vars. How can I access them from within the module?

I'm aware I can pass all the values in the actual call, but that seems really tedious.

```
--
  tasks:
     - name: tell everyone
       foo_announce: msg="tell everyone" token=x091232 uri=https://api.com
```

Versus having an appropriate set of default configuration variables and referencing those:

```
--
  tasks:
     - name: tell everyone
       foo_announce: msg="tell everyone"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

easiest to use an include file and reference it - you can specify default variables or just hard-code the defaults that way.

Personally I use variables and pass them as part of the include:

```
  tasks:
    - include: include-notification.yaml
      vars:
        themessage: "Starting on {{ inventory_hostname }}"
```

As long as your include file uses a variable called 'themessage' in the above example, it should work fine...